# Grep function not stopping with head pipe

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

So i'm currently trying to grep a single result from a random file in a specific directory. The grepping works just fine and the expected output file is populated as expected, but for some reason, even after the output file has already been filled, the process won't stop. This is the grep command where the program seems to be getting stuck.

```
searchFILE(){
case $2 in
pref)
    echo "Populating output file: $3-$1.data.out"
    dataOutputFile="$3-$1.data.out"
    zgrep -a "\"someParameter\"\:\"$1\"" /folder/anotherFolder/filetemplate.log.* | zgrep -a "\"parameter2\"\:\"$3\"" | head -1 > $dataOutputFile
;;
*)
    echo "Unrecognized command"
;;
esac
echo "Query finished"
}
```

What is currently happening is that the output file is being populated as expected with the head pipe, but for some reason I'm not getting the "Query finished" message, and the process seems not to stop at all.

Comment: The pipeline will not instantly stop when a single line has been produced. Can you check whether `zgrep` is still running and trying to find further matches?

Comment: My guess is the data is large and matches are rare. `zgrep` will run until the input is exhausted or it tries to write another match and gets SIGPIPE.

Comment: Well, the data is actually very large, but I'm interested only in one result. Shouldn't the head -1 stop the grep once one match has been found? I mean, I know for a fact that the expected result has already been found since the file is being filled as expected, but for some reason the grep doesn't seem to stop at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` does not know that `head -n1` is no longer reading from the pipe until it attempts to write to the pipe, which it will only do if another match is found. There is no direct communication between the processes. It will eventually stop, but only once all the data is read, a second match is found and `write` fails with `EPIPE`, or some other error occurs.

You can watch this happen in a simple pipeline like this:

```
cat /dev/urandom | grep -ao "12[0-9]" | head -n1
```

With a sufficiently rare pattern, you will observe a delay between output and exit.

One solution is to change your stop condition. Instead of waiting for `SIGPIPE` as your pipeline does, wait for `grep` to match once using the `-m1` option:

```
cat /dev/urandom | grep -ao -m1 "12[0-9]"
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw better performance results with `zcat myZippedFile | grep whatever` paradigm...

Answer (score 0):

The first difference you need to try is pipe with **| head -z --lines=1**

The reason is null terminated lines instead of newlines (just in case).
My example script below worked (drop the case statement to make it more simple).  If I hold onto $1 $2 inside functions things go wrong. I use parameter **$names** and only use the $1 $2 $@ once, because it also goes wrong for me if I don't and in any case you can then shift over $@ and catch arguments.  The $@ in the script itself are not the same as arguments in bash functions.

grep searching for 2 or multiple parameters **in any order** means using grep twice; in your case **zgrep | grep**.  The second grep is a normal grep!  You only need the first grep to be zgrep to do the unzip.  Your question is simpler if you drop the case statement as bash case scares off people: bash was always an ugly lady that works good for short scripts.

zgrep searches text or **compressed** text, but newlines in LINUX style vs WINDOWS are not the same. So use dos2unix to convert files so that newlines work.  I use compressed file simply because it is strange and rare to see zgrep, so it is demonstrated in a shell script with a compressed file!  It works for me.  I changed a few things, like >> and "sort -u" but you can obviously change them back.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Search for egA AND egB  using option go
# COMMAND LINE: ./zgrp egA go egB
A="$1"
cOPT="$2" # expecting case go
B="$3"
LOG="./filetemplate.log" # use parameters for long names.

# Generate some data with gzip and delete the temporary file.
echo "\"pramA\":\"$A\"  \"pramB\":\"$B\"" >> $B$A.tmp
rm -f ${LOG}.A; tar czf ${LOG}.A $B$A.tmp
rm -f $B$A.tmp
# Use paramaterise $names not $1 etc because you may want to do shift etc
searchFILE()
{
    outFile="$B-$A.data.out"
    case $cOPT in
        go) # This is zgrep | grep   NOT zgrep | zgrep 
            zgrep -a "\"pramA\":\"$A\"" ${LOG}.* | grep -a "\"pramB\":\"$B\"" | head -z --lines=1 >> $outFile
            sort -u $outFile > ${outFile}.sorted  # sort unique on your output.
            ;;
        *) echo -e "ERROR second argument must be go.\n Usage: ./zgrp egA go egB"
            exit 9
            ;;
    esac

    echo -e "\n ============ Done: $0 $@      Fin. ============="
}
searchFILE "$@"

cat ${outFile}.sorted
```